# Is it possible to remove an inline element without the elements next to it changing their position?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have 5 inline squares under a flex parent. When the button is clicked, the **first** square is removed. Each time the first square is removed, the squares that follow get pushed back to the left by one square's width (as would be expected). Is it possible to make the other squares maintain their position when this happens (i.e. they stay where they previously were instead of moving to the left)?

One way I can think of to do that is by absolutely positioning each square element. But is that the only way to prevent the squares from moving?

**Note**: I would like the squares to maintain their positions if I were to remove the **last** square as well; so something like `justify-content: flex-end` will not work for my needs because it won't work for both cases.

**Note 2**: `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` will also not work for my needs because I do need to actually remove the square element. I also plan to append another square element later and wouldn't want the layout to shift. Is this possible?

Please see the fiddle for an example.

```js
$('.click-me').on('click', function() {
  // Remove the first square.
  $('.main').children().first().remove();
});
```

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.main span {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #2e852e;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.main .square1,
.main .square5 {
  background-color: #a5a551;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click-me">Click Me!</button>
<div class="main">
  <span class="square1"></span>
  <span class="square2"></span>
  <span class="square3"></span>
  <span class="square4"></span>
  <span class="square5"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: don't remove the element, give it a class like .hidden {pointing-events:none; opacity: 0}

Comment: Create a div inside that div put the elements and those parent div will be there while its children will vanish

Comment: I have just edited my question to add a 2nd note. Basically the **visibility** or **opacity** trick won't work for me because I do actually need to remove the square element (and also plan to append another square element later on) and would like the layout to not shift in either cases. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you use a wrapper element around each div? Basically an empty div with width and height that can be filled with your squares, and if removed the wrapper acts as a placeholder. Other way that comes to mind would be setting margin-left of the next element to the previous element's width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**: You can use `grid` approach and combine it with using `CSS variables`.
Set inline style CSS variable with index of square element and then use it in CSS, to have position of this squares in main grid. In this case you can remove any of the child elements and all other will keep their positions.

```js
$('.click-me').on('click', function() {
  // Remove the first square.
  $('.main').children().first().remove();
});
```

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 35px); /* create grid with 5 columns */
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.square {
  /* make it flex and align it's content */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* make it square flexible element */
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background-color: #2e852e;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
  /* using index of element, taken from inline styles, "auto" - callback */
  grid-column-start: var(--sq-index, auto);
}

.square--active {
  background-color: #a5a551;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click-me">Click Me!</button>
<div class="main">
  <span class="square square--active" style="--sq-index: 1;">1</span>
  <span class="square" style="--sq-index: 2;">2</span>
  <span class="square" style="--sq-index: 3;">3</span>
  <span class="square" style="--sq-index: 4;">4</span>
  <span class="square square--active" style="--sq-index: 5;">5</span>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <span class="square" style="--sq-index: 2;">2</span>
  <span class="square" style="--sq-index: 4;">4</span>
  <span class="square square--active" style="--sq-index: 5;">5</span>
</div>

<!-- 
  Example of using "auto" callback.
  Defined index of first child element, 
  all next siblings will be placed automatically
-->
<div class="main">
  <span class="square" style="--sq-index: 3;">3</span>
  <span class="square">4</span>
  <span class="square square--active">5</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick! Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. If you using SCSS it could be done on much prettier way

Comment: Actually is it possible to automate this part: .square[data-index="1"] { grid-column-start: 1; } for each square element? Because I plan to append squares and so in the end I'd like the grid-column-start to be set automatically; so a square with data-index="456" will automatically have a grid-column-start: 456 etc. I'm guessing inline-styles is the only way? Lol

Comment: @FuadZeyadTareq like an option, I've updated Code Snippet to use inline CSS variables (--sq-index), in this way there is no needs to hardcode indexes (that was only example)

Comment: Thank you so much! While this works, I settled for just setting the `grid-column-start` directly through each square element's `inline-style` instead. Although, it does make the HTML more verbose and slightly harder to read (I personally think that `data-index="1"` is much easier to read). I think this is a classic use case for something like `.square { grid-column-start: attr(data-index number) }` to automate this process while keeping everything more organized and neat. But alas, it isn't supported in any browser yet (Source: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr)).